# ReactJs dont work change date format to 24hours

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Im try change my full calendar date format AM,PM to 24hours. I read official documentation and find titleFormat={hour12:false} its the solution for 24hours format. But i try this not working. Maybe who faced such a problem can help.

This my reactJs component code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

export default class Calendar extends Component {
    // declare any necessary functions such as handleDateClick, etc.
    render() {
        const events = [{ title: "today's event", date: new Date() }];
        return <FullCalendar
            initialView='timeGridWeek'
            headerToolbar={{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
            }}
            titleFormat={{
                hour12: false
            }}
            events={events}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
            allDaySlot={false}
            editable={true}
            timeFormat="H:mm"
        />
    }


}
if (document.getElementById('calendar')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Calendar />, document.getElementById('calendar'));
}
```

View:
[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat - as per the docs, titleformat controls the header, not the events. The answer below is correct, eventTimeFormat is what you need for event time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the v5 (latest) of fullcalendar, the option you're looking for is `eventTimeFormat:{ hour12: false }` I believe. If you're using a different version it'll probably be something else.

Comment: Yes im use v5 version. Im try your method but dont work.

Comment: ```
        return <FullCalendar
            initialView='timeGridWeek'
            headerToolbar={{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
            }}
            eventTimeFormat={{
                hour: "2-digit",
                minute: "2-digit",
                hour12: false
            }}
            events={events}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
            allDaySlot={false}
            editable={true}
        />
```

Comment: Full calendar version 5.8.

Comment: I need that on the left side the time has changed to 24 hours format.

Comment: @ArturKhachatryan Use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat if you want to change the format of the times on the left hand side of the grid. From your original question it wasn't actually clear which times you were talking about. But everything you need is already there in the documentation if you take the time to look carefully.